# Covert numbered date to actual date

Tags: php

How would you convert this date below into an actual date format?

```
1652122994
```

Desired output (for example):

```
2022-05-11
```

Comment: this is not a date but a timestamp.
to convert it to date :
$date=date('Y-m-d', 1652122994);

Comment: Forget about `date()` and the related functions. They are inconsistent and they cannot use more than one timezone (or using different timezones is cumbersome). Use the [`DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) and its friends instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
<?php

    $timestamp=1652122994;

    echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

?>
```

Comment: Forget about `date()`, `gmdate()` and the related functions. They are inconsistent and they cannot use more than one timezone (or using different timezones is cumbersome). Use the [`DateTime` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) and its friends instead.

Comment: For this purpose it's fine...

Comment: Yes, that can be done using the DateTime class also... `echo (new DateTime('@1652122994'))->format('Y-m-d');`